# All projects displayed in one page from MySql DB

Tags: javascript, php, css, mysqli, backend

I am working on site about some projects. I have one page named project.php that is going to display one project by some identifier. All projects have to be added to MySql db. Then php has to show data for specific project. I don't know how to make that identifier.

I have one table that is keeping posts:

```
    CREATE TABLE `posts` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `project_name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
      `img` blob NOT NULL,
      `text` text NOT NULL,
       `url` blob NOT NULL
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

How to show specific project in project.php from db when you click on the url link? Something like a dynamic web page.

Comment: This is far too broad of a question. We can help you with your code, but we can't write it for you. Look into tutorials on how to build a basic Content Management System (CMS) in PHP. It's likely that you'll end up creating a listing page that lists all projects in your table, and then each project would have a link that ends with "http://...project.php?id=123", where "123" is the `id` value from your table. Your project.php would be able to reference the id via `$_GET['id']`, and you can use that value to query your `posts` table for that `id` value.

Comment: I'll try that with CMS. I am a complete beginner, therefore I have never heard of CMS. Thank you! @RToyo

Comment: Good luck with your learning. Another term you could look into is `CRUD`, which stands for "Create, Read, Update, Delete". They're the four basic operations for working with databases, and a lot of PHP tutorials will help you `create` the project (with a form), `read` the projects (list them on a page, or view individual projects), `update` a project (with a form), and `delete` a project. Also, make sure that you __do not use__ any of the mysql_* functions. Those were completely removed in PHP7 (for good reason), but a lot of old tutorials still use them. Use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: After seeing @Karen12345's answer, I think I may have misunderstood your question. Can you clarify if you are asking how to get the `id` of the newly inserted row as Karen's answer explains? If so, I apologize for my comment about this being too broad of a question. I had interpreted your question as an attempt to display the data for a given id.

Comment: Your comment is ok, I think that CMS is is the right thing for this. Like you know you have a shop, then you create one page that is going to display a specific product that user clicked on. @RToyo

Answer (score 1):

Change the id column to an auto increment id as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE posts MODIFY COLUMN id INT auto_increment;
```

and then get the id as such after inserting each row:

```
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);
```